# How can I aggregate all validation errors on a Google Sheet into a list of cells references?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I set up Validation for column `A` such that the only valid values are one of `Apple`, `Orange` or `Pear`. I apply the validation rule to the entire column.

The problem is, let's say, my sheet has 10,000 rows so it takes ages to scroll through all of them to check whether each and every cell are valid.

Most of the cells have valid data. Some don't.

Is there a way I can get a list of those offending cells, without having to manually scroll through the 10,000 rows and looking very carefully for the little validation error orange triangle indicator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test that the 10,000 cells in column A have a value `Apple`, `Orange` or `Pear`, using a formula in column B. For example the formula below gives a `Yes` if the value is one of the three fruits, and `No` otherwise. Copy it into cell B1, then drag down to the bottom of your range (e.g. B10000). Then you add a filter and look at the Yes's or No's separately (e.g. to delete the No's).

```
=if(countif({"Pear","Orange","Apple"},A1),"Yes","No")
```

Also, you can set data validation to reject inputs that don't match your desired values if you want. Click the `Reject Input` option in the `On Invalid Data` menu option in the validation popup window.

Ben

Comment: Hmmmmmm. Good answer for my specific question — but what if I changed the validation rules?

The actual validation rule I'm using takes values from another worksheet. It's impractical to update this "countif" expression every time...? Or perhaps there's a way to essentially duplicate the validation logic inside of a countif...

Comment: You could refer to a range instead of the specific values, like so:  **=if(countif($D$1:$D$10,A1),"Yes","No")**  where in this case the list of valid inputs are in cells **D1:D10** (but this can be whatever range you want).